# Get Python to output a .py file from a dictionary?

Tags: python, pickle

How can I get Python to output and save a `.py` file that has been generated from a dictionary?

For example I want to produce this file dynamically:

`file.py`:

```
import time

PROJECT_NAME = "YOUR_PROJECT_NAME"
USER = "TEST USER"
```

from the following dictionary:

```
{'PROJECT_NAME': 'YOUR_PROJECT_NAME', 'USER': 'TEST'}
```

This is what I have tried:

```
 with open('file.py', 'wb') as handle:
            pickle.dump(values, handle)
```

but this gave:

```
(dp0
S'PROJECT_NAME'
p1
S'USER'
p2
```

Comment: An obvious way would be to write your own parser, shouldn't take too long. Question is - do you need to use pickle?

Comment: @Andrew Jaffe I'll be using time in one of the settings i.e. RELEASE = time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')

Comment: so you mean to loop each item and output like that? @Aleksander Lidtke

Comment: Yes something along the lines: `for k, i in yourDict.iteritems(): fileHandle.write( "{} = {}".format(k, i) )`

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke that seemed to work but what is {} = {}

Comment: `"{}".format()" is just a newer way that does string formatting like e.g. `"'%s' : '%s'," % (k,v)`. A lot more portable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
with open('file.py', 'wb') as handle:
    handle.write("{")
    for k,v in your_dict.iteritems():
        handle.write("'%s' : '%s'," % (k,v))
    handle.write("}\n")
```

Comment: Strangely, this isn't what the question actually asks to produce (despite being accepted...)!